# Complex roots of equation with geometric sequence?

Tags: complex-numbers

1 + z + z^2 + z^3 = 0

How to find the solutions to this one?

My workbook tells me to use the fact that it's a geometric sequence, but I haven't worked with them at all, so I am not sure I know what to do with that hint.

Answer (score 1):

Sum of this is:
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
Try expanding:
$$(x-1)(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n)$$
Or use long division:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c}
x-1&x^{n+1}-1&x^n\\
&x^{n+1}-x^n\\\hline
x-1&x^n-1&x^{n-1}\\
&x^n-x^{n-1}\\\hline
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\
\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\\hline
x-1&x-1&1\\
&x-1\\\hline
&0
&\end{array}$$
So:
$$1+x+x^2+x^3=\frac{x^4-1}{x-1}\quad x\ne1$$
So: $$x^4=1\implies x=\pm i,-1$$

Comment: Except `1`, I suppose?

Comment: @lisyarus nope.

Comment: So you have found another expression for the original polynomial. What next?

Comment: @almagest do you know about n-th roots of 1?

Comment: OF course I do, but he doesn't or he would not have asked the question!

Comment: @Jon see the edit

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}1+z+z^2+z^3&=0\\
(1+z+z^2+z^3+\color{red}{z^4+z^5+z^6+\cdots} )-(\color{red}{z^4+z^5+z^6+\cdots})&=0\\
\color{blue}{(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots )}-z^4\color{blue}{(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots )}&=0\\
(1-z^4)\color{blue}{(1+z+z^2+z^3+\cdots )}&=0\\
(1-z^4)\cdot \color{blue}{\frac 1{1-z}}&=0\\
z^4&=1  \quad (z\neq1 )\\
z&=i,-1,-i
\end{align}$$

Or, more correctly, 
$$z=\left(2n+\frac r2\right)\pi$$
where
$n=0,\pm1, \pm2, \cdots $
and $r=1,2,3$.